# como ocultar los inactivos (I) de una tabla y mostrar los activos(A) segun sea el periodo?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, api

tengo una tabla que muestra activos e inactivos de unos datos obtenidos por una api, mi código debería ocultar los valores inactivos marcados como I cuando el periodo sea el actual y mostrar los activos , cuando sea un periodo pasado debe mostrar el periodo actual con sus datos correspondientes ,utilice el método splice pero no me funciona bien , al llegar a los 38 datos del array se corta el bucle del for y muestra todos los activos pero algunos inactivos , como podría hacer para mostrar solo los activos con su periodo cuando sea el actual y cuando sea un periodo pasado mostrar la información correspondiente?
Mi código JS:

```
  periodos:[],
    estadosPeriodos:[], 
    periodoActual: 0,
    estadoActual:'',
    headers: [
      {
        align: 'start',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name',
      },
      { text: 'Letra', value: 'letra' },
      { text: 'Alicuota ', value: 'alicuota'},
      { text: 'Periodo ', value: 'periodo',sortable:false },
      { text: 'Estado ', value: 'estado',sortable:false },
      { text: 'Acciones', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
    ],
    desserts: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
   
      Letra: [],
      Alicuota: 0,
      Periodo: 0,
      Estado: 0,
    },
    defaultItem: {
     
      Letra: [],
      Alicuota: 0,
      Periodo: 0,
      Estado: 0, 
for(let j=0;j<this.desserts.length;j++){

      if(this.periodoActual.toString() != this.desserts[j].periodo.toString()){
       this.desserts.splice( [j] , 1 )
      //mostrar informacion de tabla con periodo y estado correspondiente
      }
      
     }
```

código HTML :

```
 <v-btn
                    @click="periodoAnterior"
                    class="mx-2"
                    fab
                    dark
                    small
                    color="primary"
                  >
                    <v-icon dark>
                      mdi-minus
                    </v-icon>
                  </v-btn> <span
                               
                  > <strong>{{ periodoActual }}</strong>
                  </span>
                  <v-btn
                @click="periodoSiguiente"
                  class="mx-2"
                  fab
                  dark
                  small
                  color="primary"
                >
                  <v-icon dark>
                    mdi-plus
                  </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-btn-toggle>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
              </v-spacer>
              <v-spacer> 
                <div class="text-center">
               <span
                 
               >
              <strong>Estado:{{estadoActual}}</strong> 
                </span>
             </div>
           </v-spacer>
                <v-dialog
                  v-model="dialog"
                  max-width="500px"
                >
 <v-container  
                      >
                        <v-row>
                          <v-col
                            cols="12"
                            sm="6"
                            md="4"
                          >
                            <v-text-field
                          
                              v-model="editedItem.letra"
                              label="Letra"
                              
                            ></v-text-field>
                          </v-col>
                          <v-col
                            cols="12"
                            sm="6"
                            md="4"
                          >
                            <v-text-field
                            class="alicuota-tabla"
                              v-model="editedItem.alicuota"
                              label="Alicuota"
                            ></v-text-field>
                          </v-col>
                          <v-col
                            cols="12"
                            sm="6"
                            md="4"
                          >
                            <v-text-field
                              v-model="editedItem.periodo"
                              label="Periodo"
                            ></v-text-field>
                          </v-col>
                          <v-col
                            cols="12"
                            sm="6"
                            md="4"
                          >
                            <v-text-field
                              v-model="editedItem.estado"
                              label="Estado"
                            ></v-text-field>
                          </v-col>
                       
                        </v-row>
                      </v-container>
```

gracias

Comment: Hola amigo, pregunta jej, por que usar vanilla para ocultar contenido si con vue ya puedes ocultar contenido?? Es como usar vue solo para los vfor jaja, sabes que puedes poner una condicional con v-show o v-if? onda v-if="item.peridoActual", si el periodo es actual, se muestra si no no, y va solo es un ejemplo porque no entiendo tu data, podrías formatearla solo con los datos importantes y te puedo hacer una respuesta.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es a que no se específicamente si ese dato te sirve para saber el periodo actual o cual, porque tienes como tres datos que dicen lo mismo, pero no es necesario meter vanilla para eso, en todo caso podrias meter una computed que te retorne el path del objeto si es muy largo..

Comment: la verdad no sabia de los vfor p vif ,soy nuevo en vue jaja pero voy a averiguar como funcionan gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedo apoyarte mencionando que, haciendolo como tienes tu código actualmente, debes corregir el for que usas, ya que estás modificando el for que andas a su ves recorriendo. Esto te genera problemas, debido a lo siguiente:

```
// recorres el Array this.desserts, supongamos que tienes 5 elementos
for(let j=0;j<this.desserts.length;j++){

   // Verificamos el periodo si es igual o diferente
   if(this.periodoActual.toString() != this.desserts[j].periodo.toString()){ 

       /** Al ser diferentes los periodos, removemos el elemento en
       la posicion actual, si antes el arreglo tenia 5 elementos
       va a tener 4, asi que el elemento siguiente pasa a ocupar la posicion actual y j al siguiente recorrido, va a buscar la posicion siguiente, por ende no va a anaizar el item que antes iba a ser el siguiente*/
       this.desserts.splice( [j] , 1 );
       //mostrar informacion de tabla con periodo y estado correspondiente
}
```

En sí, sería anexar otra linea de código a tu for en el if, que después de remover el item de tu arreglo, le reduzca el valor de la variable j, es decir:

```
j--;
```

o

```
j = j-1;
```

quedando el for de la siguiente manera:

```
for(let j=0;j<this.desserts.length;j++){

    if(this.periodoActual.toString() != this.desserts[j].periodo.toString()){
    this.desserts.splice( [j] , 1 );
    j--; // Le reducimos el valor de la variable j para que proceda a analizar el nuevo elemento en la posición nueva
    //mostrar informacion de tabla con periodo y estado correspondiente
}
```

Para aportar un poco más al conocimiento te comparto como hacer el uro de v-for y v-if o v-show en vue js para que en el momento que puedas, pruebes como te resulta mejor realizar lo que quieres.

[v-for en vuejs](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/09/11/vuejs-display-a-list-of-items-with-v-for)

[v-if en vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if)

[v-show en vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)

Cabe mencionar que el v-if y el v-show a pesar de que visualemente cumplen lo que necesitas, tienen una diferencia y es que el v-show afecta el display de tu css para ocultar dichos elementos que no deseas mostrar, mientras que el v-if afecta el renderizado de la aplicación haciendo que no se puedan observar dichos elementos ni siquiera en el código. "Inspeccionar elementos"

Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola me parece que aunque está muy bien que apoyes y que corrijas el codigo del compañero, pero esto es un mal uso del framework que está utilizando, sería mas correcto explicarle como debería funcionar en cuanto a el lo tiene ya, y tambien enseñarle la forma correcta con vue, porque es mega overkilled para hacer algo que vue te hace con dos palabras de código.

Comment: lo implemente asi como dijiste y funciono pero solo para el primer periodo, al cambiarlo muestra lo mismo

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford concuerdo con lo que mencionas, el problema es que no siempre se deben hacer las correcciones al instante, puede que lo que está haciendo no es la manera más optima, debido a que el framework ofrece algo de una manera mas sencilla, no quiere decir que esté mal implementarlo por sus medios, de igual manera le corregí el error que tenía pensando en la posibilidad de no poder hacer todo el cambio ahora. Pero si es recomendable que intente comprender cual es la manera mas correcta y sacar el tiempo para realizar dicho ajuste

Comment: @RodrigoCamacho lo que pasa es que al parecer, debes estar modificando directamente la información que recibes, te recomiendo que si deseas hacerlo así uses una variable que almacene toda la info y al realizar el análisis de nuevo cuando cambie el periodo, lo que tengas que hacer es volver la variable que usas para llenar la info de la tabla inicializandola con la variable que almacena toda la data que se obtuvo y ya hacerle el recorrido o modificación a la variable que caraga tu tabla